# TwinCAT 3: Login via ADS route not possible (Internal error:System.NullReferenceException)

Tags: routes, ads, plc, twincat-ads

I have a Beckhoff TwinCAT 3 Project which is compileable.
I am able to log in on the machine directly (without ADS route).
As soon as I try to login via ADS route from a remote Computer (with online Change) I get an error message:
`Ads-Error 0x2AF9: A unknown Ads-Error has occured.`
`Internal error:System.NullReferenceException: Object reference not set to an instance of an object.`
I use the same TwinCAT-Version on the machine and the remote Computer (TwinCAT v3.1.4022.22). So this should not be a problem.
Login without any code Change is possible, so I can see all variables. But I'm not able to Change anything because of this error. That's weird.

Comment: This sound like a problem that should be asked from Beckhoff. I have managed to fix some online change problems by cleaning the PLC project and rebuilding it. Of course, try to delete the route and add it again (with IP address, not host name checked). Try the cleaning from both "Build -> Clean solution" as well as right click the PLC project in the project explorer and select "clean". After that, select "Build -> Rebuild solution". And please, if you get it working please update here too!

Comment: The Problem is only with online Change. A complete download of the program is working. I already had Beckhoff on my Computer via TeamViewer. First Problem was that the AMS-Net-ID has to finish with '.1.1'. Beckhoff was not able to tell me, why online Change doesn't work.

Comment: Ok. Have you tried to create a new blank project if it's working with online change? If it works, try to copy everything from the broken project to the new one. If it's not, then you could perhaps try a reinstall TwinCAT on both your computer and the target PLC.

Comment: I can't test this with a new project because the machine is in a state where I am not allowed to test this...

Answer (score 0):

Which version of Visual Studio are you using? I find that sometimes the window that has focus can cause a similar error.

I would also check:

1. That the target has a valid TC Configuration (reactivate and restart TC on the Target.
2. That your project target is correct. There is a dropdown box next to the target dropdown that should indicate the project you are trying to download. *This is only relevant if you have multiple projects in your solution*
3. That your port number is correct (851 as standard, but if you've moved projects around in your solution it can become confused).